# Scrapy shell return without response

Tags: python, python-3.x, attributeerror, scrapy-shell

I have a little problem with scrapy to crawl a website. I followed the tutorial of scrapy to learn how crawl a website and I was interested to test it on the site 'https://www.leboncoin.fr' but the spider doesn't work. So, I tried :

```
scrapy shell 'https://www.leboncoin.fr'
```

But, I haven't a response of the site.

```
$ scrapy shell 'https://www.leboncoin.fr'
2017-05-16 08:31:26 [scrapy.utils.log] INFO: Scrapy 1.3.3 started (bot: all_cote)
2017-05-16 08:31:26 [scrapy.utils.log] INFO: Overridden settings: {'BOT_NAME': 'all_cote', 'DUPEFILTER_CLASS':    'scrapy.dupefilters.BaseDupeFilter', 'LOGSTATS_INTERVAL': 0,   'NEWSPIDER_MODULE': 'all_cote.spiders', 'ROBOTSTXT_OBEY': True, 'SPIDER_MODULES': ['all_cote.spiders']}
2017-05-16 08:31:27 [scrapy.middleware] INFO: Enabled extensions:
['scrapy.extensions.corestats.CoreStats',
 'scrapy.extensions.telnet.TelnetConsole']
2017-05-16 08:31:27 [scrapy.middleware] INFO: Enabled downloader middlewares:
['scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.robotstxt.RobotsTxtMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.httpauth.HttpAuthMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.downloadtimeout.DownloadTimeoutMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.defaultheaders.DefaultHeadersMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.useragent.UserAgentMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.retry.RetryMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.redirect.MetaRefreshMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.httpcompression.HttpCompressionMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.redirect.RedirectMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.cookies.CookiesMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.stats.DownloaderStats']
2017-05-16 08:31:27 [scrapy.middleware] INFO: Enabled spider middlewares:
['scrapy.spidermiddlewares.httperror.HttpErrorMiddleware',
 'scrapy.spidermiddlewares.offsite.OffsiteMiddleware',
 'scrapy.spidermiddlewares.referer.RefererMiddleware',
 'scrapy.spidermiddlewares.urllength.UrlLengthMiddleware',
 'scrapy.spidermiddlewares.depth.DepthMiddleware']
2017-05-16 08:31:27 [scrapy.middleware] INFO: Enabled item pipelines:[]
2017-05-16 08:31:27 [scrapy.extensions.telnet] DEBUG: Telnet console listening on 127.0.0.1:6023
2017-05-16 08:31:27 [scrapy.core.engine] INFO: Spider opened
2017-05-16 08:31:27 [scrapy.core.engine] DEBUG: Crawled (200) <GET https://www.leboncoin.fr/robots.txt> (referer: None)
2017-05-16 08:31:27 [scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.robotstxt] DEBUG: Forbidden by robots.txt: <GET https://www.leboncoin.fr>
2017-05-16 08:31:28 [traitlets] DEBUG: Using default logger
2017-05-16 08:31:28 [traitlets] DEBUG: Using default logger
[s] Available Scrapy objects:
[s]   scrapy     scrapy module (contains scrapy.Request, scrapy.Selector, etc)
[s]   crawler    <scrapy.crawler.Crawler object at 0x1039fbd30>
[s]   item       {}
[s]   request    <GET https://www.leboncoin.fr>
[s]   settings   <scrapy.settings.Settings object at 0x10716b8d0>
[s] Useful shortcuts:
[s]   fetch(url[, redirect=True]) Fetch URL and update local objects (by default, redirects are followed)
[s]   fetch(req)                  Fetch a scrapy.Request and update local objects 
[s]   shelp()           Shell help (print this help)
[s]   view(response)    View response in a browser
```

If I use :

```
view(response)
```

An AttributeError is printed...

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-1-2c2544195c90> in <module>()
----> 1 view(response)

/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/scrapy/utils/response.py in open_in_browser(response, _openfunc)
     67     from scrapy.http import HtmlResponse, TextResponse
     68     # XXX: this implementation is a bit dirty and could be improved
---> 69     body = response.body
     70     if isinstance(response, HtmlResponse):
     71         if b'<base' not in body:
```

### AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'body'

### Edit 1 :

To rrschmidt : the complete log was updated and when I run

```
fetch('https:www.leboncoin.fr')
```

I receive this :

```
2017-05-16 08:33:15 [scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.robotstxt] DEBUG: Forbidden by robots.txt: <GET https://www.leboncoin.fr>
```

---

So, How can I fix it ?

Thanks for your answers,

Chris

Comment: Which tutorial? So we know what exactly you were doing. And, at which step you're stuck in it.

Comment: I used : https://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/intro/tutorial.html to learn how make a spider and the different techniques. The part of the shell is interesting so, I wanted to apply it on this website.

Comment: What happens when you request the URL again by running `fetch('https://www.leboncoin.fr')` from the scrapy shell? Can you also please post the complete log starting with the line that contains scrapy's version number?

Comment: It looks like the website has forbidden the scraping of the site via robots.txt -> DEBUG: Forbidden by robots.txt

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It looks like the website has restricted scraping via robots.txt. Its usually polite to respect that wish.

But if you really want to scrape the site you can change scrapy's default behaviour by changing the ROBOTSTXT_OBEY setting to false in your settings.py

```
ROBOTSTXT_OBEY=False
```

Comment: Thanks for you answer, I understand now why is gonna break when the spider is running.