# Scrapy AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'css'

Tags: python, css, scrapy

I'm trying to scrape details from this page using Scrapy: link

This is the command I am using to pull the Title but it is throwing an error:

`response.css('#intitule > div.nom_fugitif::text').extract_first()`

This is the error:

> ---
>
> AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call
>   last)  in ()
>
> ----> 1 response.css('#intitule > div.nom_fugitif::text').extract_first()
>
> AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'css'

It says the div has no CSS but I'm not sure what that means because it does have a CSS class.

Comment: Look at the value of `response`. It must be `None`.

Comment: @araraonline I'm really new to this. Can you explain it more please?

Comment: The error doesn't say that HTML element doesn't have CSS class, it says that `response` object is `None`, hence doesn't have a method `css` that you call in `response.css(...)`. Please show complete code so we can examine.

Comment: Type `print(response)` and you will see it probably is `None`.

Comment: It just started working again. No idea why! But thanks for the help regardless :)

Comment: It could be that `ROBOTSTXT_OBEY` is set to `True` in your spider's settings.py: https://stackoverflow.com/a/43994382/1011724

Answer (score 1):

NoneType means you're actually getting None in your response. 
You can check with

```
if response is not None:
```